# JpaRepository: No Transaction in progress

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data Jpa along with hibernate. I have a repository that extends JpaRepository and I'm using it to save records to the database. But when I call .flush(), the following error occurs.

I've seen other questions with a similar error but after trying to use @Transaction in the repository as well, I get the same error.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:397)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:365)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 75 more
```

The Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface AttributeRepository extends JpaRepository<Attribute, Long> {
    Attribute findById(long id);
}
```

My config contains the entity manager factory and the platform transaction manager that JPA requires,

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(BoneCPDataSource ds) throws IOException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(ds);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.scripps.branch.entity" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

The Service where the saveandFlush() method is called,

```
@Service
public interface FeatureService {

    @Transactional
    public List<Feature> rankFeatures(Instances data, List<String> entrezIds, Dataset d);
}
```

Just to add, I'm injecting the repository using `@Autowired` into the implementation of the service.

Comment: Yes I have the annotation. I'm able to retrieve objects using the repository but not able to save and flush an entity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to enable Jpa Transaction or to associate Spring Data with the transaction manager:

Ex enable transaction management:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

Ex associate transaction manager with Jpa Repositories:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(transactionManagerRef="transactionManager", 
    entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory", 
    value="com.repositories.pkg.location" )
```

Comment: I've used both `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "org.scripps.branch.repository" })` in my config. 
Note: THe repository is able to query data, the error is thrown only when I use `flush()`

Comment: Are you using the mentioned AspectJ approach or a proxy-based approach? Try the latter as it is simpler to set up.

Comment: The error message says 'no transaction is in progress' so I figure it would be something in configuration. Maybe Hille is right could be something with your transaction mode Aspect or proxy. Witch one your are using?

Answer (score 1):

Annotating your repository with `@Transactional` won't help; you have to annotate the service method with `@Transactional`. "service method" meaning the method encapsulating both, the call into the `save` method of the repo and the `flush` call.

Comment: I've added `@Transactional` to the service method but I still get the same error. I'm using an interface for the service and I've annotated the method in the interface and its implementation with `@Transactional`.

Comment: As a side note, quoting from the spring reference: `Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes)
with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces.` It won't do any harm annotating twice, but it may be confusing.

Comment: Oh, no. You got me wrong :-). Programming against the service interface is a good practice; so keep your interface as well as an implementation. Just do not annotate twice (the interface + the implementation) but rather once (the implementation).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. My configuration files were divided into 2 classes one for the Application Context and one for Persistence Context. I combined both of them and the error vanished.

Comment: Not completely sure why though.

Comment: Strange. Has any of your config classes been declared `final` or did not have a parameterless constructor? Good to hear it works at least.